# printing a div not coming out properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am attempting to print a div that is formatted to fit on a letter sheet of paper.

In css, I have laid out this page to look like the following:
[image]

But, when I print, I get this [image]

The div's on the right side are not printed on the right, but their outlines are there. Instead the text contained inside them is pushed to the next page.

I'm not really sure where I went wrong or what is happening.

Here is my code:

my style outside the "paperA4" div:

```
    .paperA4 {
        width: 8.5in;
        height: 11in;
        border: 1px solid white;
        margin: auto;
        padding-left: .5in;
        padding-right: .5in;
        padding-top: .5in;
        padding-bottom: .5in;
    }
```

Inside of my print div:

```
<div id="print">

    <style>

    .paperA4 {
        width: 8.5in;
        height: 11in;
        border: 1px solid white;
        margin: auto;
        padding-left: .5in;
        padding-right: .5in;
        padding-top: .5in;
        padding-bottom: .5in;
    }

    .card-shell {
        width:100%;
        height:2in;
        border: 1px solid blue;
    }

    .in-card {
        width:50%;
        height:100%;
        border: 1px solid red;
        float: left;
    }
    </style>

    <div class="paperA4">

        <div class="card-shell">

            <div class="in-card">
                test
            </div>

            <div class="in-card">
                test
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="card-shell">

            <div class="in-card">
                test
            </div>

            <div class="in-card">
                test
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="card-shell">

            <div class="in-card">
                test
            </div>

            <div class="in-card">
                test
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="card-shell">

            <div class="in-card">
                test
            </div>

            <div class="in-card">
                test
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="card-shell">

            <div class="in-card">
                test
            </div>

            <div class="in-card">
                test
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

My printing function:

```
function PrintElem(elem)
{
    var mywindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=400,width=600');

    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>' + document.title  + '</title>');
    mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
    mywindow.document.write('<h1>' + document.title  + '</h1>');
    mywindow.document.write(document.getElementById(elem).innerHTML);
    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

    mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
    mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10*/

    mywindow.print();
    mywindow.close();

    return true;
}
```

Comment: does it happen on all browsers?

Comment: comment  mywindow.print();
    mywindow.close(); these lines and check what you see.

Comment: @techLove Just tested it, I am currently using Chrome. It does the same thing on Edge.

Comment: @techLove It's the same except it's not a print dialogue. Just opens the contents in its own page. In this page the formatting is broken just like in the pictures I attached.

Comment: just saying, you have the size of a A4 paper not A5

Comment: @Edwin Thank you

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton you can inspect element in that view to find out the problem

Comment: @techLove The inspected code looks correct to me, all my divs are there and they are all the right size

Comment: have you to try to add to your css `@media print {@page {size: A4;}}` and btw is the page right displayed in the browser viewer? Eventually if the format is broken in the viewer you can add the css classes in this @media too.

Comment: you can try adding display:flex; like here: .card-shell {
        width:100%; display:flex;
        height:2in;
        border: 1px solid blue;
    } but keep in mind http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: @techLove Can you post this as an answer please? It worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try adding display:flex; like here:

```
.card-shell { width:100%; display:flex; height:2in; border: 1px solid blue; }
```

but keep in mind [caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)